# Linux static compilation issue

Tags: fedora, compiling, static-linking

I am building testdisk as static and run

> make static

it returns the following error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What's the problem?

In the makefile I have the following line

> LIBS = -lz -lntfs -luuid -lcrypto
> -lext2fs -lcom_err

and I am getting error on all the floowing flags

> -luuid -lcrypto  -lext2fs -lcom_err

Comment: Do you have `libuuid.a` library installed?

Comment: If you don't the debian/ubuntu package that contains it is called `uuid-dev`

Comment: I have libuuid.so in /usr/lib but not libuuid.a. How to install it.

Comment: I am using Fedora 13.

Answer (score 5):

The [RPM packages for libuuid-devel](http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libuuid-devel) for Fedora 13 appear to contain only the shared library. Therefore you'd have to build it [from source](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) if you need a static library.

I expect that this is the same problem with a static `-lcrypto` and the others.

However, if it is [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) specifically that you are trying to compile, you probably shouldn't bother as the partition repair utility is part of most LiveCD distributions, including Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is given by [resolution of Red Hat bug report 596898](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=596898). Essentially, static libraries are strongly discouraged, as they force at least relinking if/when a bug is fixed. They consume disk and memory space, particularly for commonly used functionality.